# vb.net connect to sql server 2008 - login failed for user' '

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, connection-string

I'm currently upgrading my sql server from 2005 to 2008 enterprise server. I used VB to connect to the database. It worked fine in the previous version of sql, but when upgrading it seems doesn't recognize my connection string.

Below is my connection string:

```
myConnection = New SqlConnection("server=RAVY-PC\RAVY;uid=;pwd=;database=CIEDC");
myConnection.Open();
```

Where `Ravy-PC\RAVY` is my server name at the sql server login dialogue box. And I used the `windows authentication` mode.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks guy for viewing....

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/191576/sql-server-cant-connect/191587#191587

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this connection string:

```
Server=RAVY-PC\RAVY;Database=CIEDC;Trusted_Connection=True;
```